TYPO3 Flux - flux "Page Configuration" tab missing on translated pages
We have an old project running on TYPO3 7.6 with Flux 8.2.
The translation is running for the rest of the page but if we want to go to translated version, in the page configuration the flux' "page configuration" tab is missing, in which flux form values are saved and contains translatable data.
The configuration looks about the following:
<f:section name="Configuration">
  [...]
  <flux:form id="news">
    <flux:form.sheet name="defaultSettings" label="Global Settings">
      [...]
      <flux:field.input name="settings.addSubtitle.text" default="" label="...">
      </flux:field.input>
      <flux:field.text name="settings.text" label="...">
      </flux:field.text>
      [...]
    </flux:form.sheet>
  </flux:form>
  [...]
</f:section>

I could not identify what to do to enable or display the translation of this tab.
As a result in the frontend it only show the original language fields.
Of what I think I have identified, there is an issue that a translation behaviour was removed from TYPO3 core which causes an incompatiblity with Flux field translation.
It was stated, that I need EXT:compatibility6, which I installed, but no help.
It also mentioned to add e.g.:
<flux:form.option name="translation" value="separate" />

which I did add below the form tag, but it did not help.
Any suggestions? I might just have a minor issue in addition the translation option I think and then it should work with the compatibility plugin. It's quite difficult to find information for this old software.
I would like to avoid add fields outside of flux for that project and migrate the data. But I do not see any other way yet.
